# Delete a specific cookie on the whole website

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to be able to delete a specific cookie on a wordpress-site, from a random page on the website, by the push of a button (or another element). But so far I only succeed deleting the cookie, from the same page it was created on.

I call the function from the button/element by placing the code: `onclick="deleteCookie1();"`.

The name of the function to place the cookie is: `onclick="setCookie1();"` .

The code is placed in the Head section.

I need to delete the cookie from the whole website, from another page than the page the cookie was created on, by a click on an element.

The name of the cookie is 'SDSEOname', the value is '7'.

```
<script>
function deleteCookie1(){
    document.cookie = "SDSEOname=7; path=http://page.net/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;"; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: the `path` parameter is not a URL. It's just the path from the website root, like `path=/`

Comment: If the cookie was originally set on a subdirectory, changing it at the root won't have any effect on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a great explanation here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp